# Pythonで特定の文字列を含むかをcontains()を使って判断する関数

Tags: python3, pandas

Pythonでtrain['name']という文字列項目に対して、特定の文字列（例えば、"aaa"）を含む場合は"1"、含まない場合は"0"となる項目（train['test']）を別で作りたいと思っています。その際、以下のような関数（kansu1やkansu2）を作り、apply関数でセットしようとしたのですが、エラーとなってうまくいかず、どこに問題があるのか教えていただけないでしょうか。

```
def test_kansu1(s):
    if s.contains('aaa'):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

train['test'] = train['name'].apply(lambda x: test_kansu1(x))
```

--> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

```
def test_kansu2(s):
    if s.str.contains('aaa'):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

train['test'] = train['name'].apply(lambda x: test_kansu2(x))
```

--> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Comment: 「train['name']という文字列項目」や「apply関数でセットしようとした」という文章から推測すると、pandas.DataFrameの話をしていますか？

Comment: @merino はい、DataFrameのことです。作ろうと思っていた関数では引数にDataFrameの項目を渡して処理しようとしていました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def test_kansu1(s):
    # if s.contains('aaa'):  # <-- str 型インスタンスに contains メソッドが無いのでエラー
    if 'aaa' in s:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def test_kansu2(s):
    # if s.str.contains('aaa'):  # <-- str 型インスタンスに str という属性(attribute)が無いのでエラー
    if 'aaa' in s:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

`pandas.Series.str.contains()` を使用する場合。

```py
import pandas as pd

train = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['01_aaa', '02_bbb', '03_ccc', '04_ddd', '05_eee']
})

train['test'] = train['name'].str.contains('aaa') * 1
print(train)

#      name  test
# 0  01_aaa     1
# 1  02_bbb     0
# 2  03_ccc     0
# 3  04_ddd     0
# 4  05_eee     0
```